# Wordpress get_posts by category

Tags: wordpress

I have the following bit of code:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'category'         => 7,
    'orderby'          => 'name',
    'order'            => 'ASC',
    'post_type'        => 'product'
);

$posts = get_posts($args);var_dump($posts);
```

This should return one post I know that is in the category, but it isn't. If I leave out the 'category'-argument, I get all the products, so I know this should normally work. If I change the category to 1 and take out my custom post type (product), I get my default posts.

I can't see what's wrong with this. Can anyone spot what the problem is?

Comment: Could the -1 voter please tell me why he downvoted? Same for the close vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like you could accomplish the same thing but with WP_Query. This gets the post type "Product" with "posts_per_page" for the amount of posts, and "product_cat" for the product category. Hope this helps!

EDIT: If you'd like to do it your way maybe instead of "category" try "product_cat"

```
<ul class="products">
    <?php
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'product_cat' => 'shoes', 'orderby' => 'rand' );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>

            <h2>Shoes</h2>

                <li class="product">    

                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID); ?>">

                        <?php woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash( $post, $product ); ?>

                        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" width="300px" height="300px" />'; ?>

                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

                        <span class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></span>                    

                    </a>

                    <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product ); ?>

                </li>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul><!--/.products-->
```